# ffmpeg: programmatically use libavcodec and encode and decode raw bitmap, all in just few milliseconds and small compressed size on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, codec, libavcodec

We need to compress the size of the 1024x2048 image we produce, to size of about jpeg (200-500kb) from raw 32bits RGBA (8Mb) on Raspberry Pi 4. All in c/c++ program.

The compression needs to be just in few milliseconds, otherwise it is pointless to us.

We decided to try supported encoding using ffmpeg dev library and c/c++ code.

The problem we are facing is that when we edited [example of the encoding](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/encode_video.c), provided by ffmpeg developers, the times we are dealing are unacceptable.

Here you can see the edited code where the frames are created:

```
for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
#ifdef MEASURE_TIME
        auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "START Encoding frame...\n";
#endif
    fflush(stdout);

    ret = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
    if (ret < 0)
        exit(1);

    //I try here, to convert our 32 bits RGBA image to YUV pixel format:

    for (y = 0; y < c->height; y++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < c->width; x++)
        {
            int imageIndexY = y * frame->linesize[0] + x;

            uint32_t rgbPixel = ((uint32_t*)OutputDataImage)[imageIndexY];

            double Y, U, V;
            uint8_t R = rgbPixel << 24;
            uint8_t G = rgbPixel << 16;
            uint8_t B = rgbPixel << 8;

            YUVfromRGB(Y, U, V, (double)R, (double)G, (double)B);
            frame->data[0][imageIndexY] = (uint8_t)Y;

            if (y % 2 == 0 && x % 2 == 0)
            {
                int imageIndexU = (y / 2) * frame->linesize[1] + (x / 2);
                int imageIndexV = (y / 2) * frame->linesize[2] + (x / 2);

                frame->data[1][imageIndexU] = (uint8_t)U;
                frame->data[2][imageIndexV] = (uint8_t)Y;
            }
        }
    }

    frame->pts = i;

    /* encode the image */
    encode(c, frame, pkt, f);

#ifdef MEASURE_TIME
        auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto time = end_time - start_time;
        std::cout << "FINISHED Encoding frame in: " << time / std::chrono::milliseconds(1) << "ms.\n";

#endif
    }
```

Here are some important parts of the previous parts of that function:

```
codec_name = "mpeg4";

codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(codec_name);

c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    
c->bit_rate = 1000000;  
c->width = IMAGE_WIDTH;
c->height = IMAGE_HEIGHT;
c->gop_size = 1;
c->max_b_frames = 1;
c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
```

*IMAGE_WIDTH* and *IMAGE_HEIGHT* are 1024 and 2048 corresponding.

The result I have ran on Raspberry Pi 4 look like this:

```
START Encoding frame...
Send frame   0
FINISHED Encoding frame in: 40ms.
START Encoding frame...
Send frame   1
Write packet   0 (size=11329)
FINISHED Encoding frame in: 60ms.
START Encoding frame...
Send frame   2
Write packet   1 (size=11329)
FINISHED Encoding frame in: 58ms.
```

Since I am completely green in encoding and using codecs, **my question will be how to do it the best way and correct way, meaning the way which would reduce timing to few ms, and I am not sure the codec was chosen the best for the job, or the pixel format.**

The rest of the meaningful code you can see here (the *encode()* function you can find in the ffmpeg developer example I gave link to above):

```
void RGBfromYUV(double& R, double& G, double& B, double Y, double U, double V)
{
    Y -= 16;
    U -= 128;
    V -= 128;
    R = 1.164 * Y + 1.596 * V;
    G = 1.164 * Y - 0.392 * U - 0.813 * V;
    B = 1.164 * Y + 2.017 * U;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this :

int RgbToYuv(uint8_t *rgb, AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx, AVFrame * pFrame)
{

enum AVPixelFormat yuv420p_pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, bgra_pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_BGRA;

// Allocate video frame
//pFrame=av_frame_alloc();

// Allocate an AVFrame structure
AVFrame * pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();
if(pFrameRGB==NULL) return 0;

// Assign appropriate parts of buffer to image planes in pFrameRGB
// Note that pFrameRGB is an AVFrame, but AVFrame is a superset
// of AVPicture

avpicture_fill((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB, rgb, bgra_pix_fmt, pCodecCtx->width, pCodecCtx->height);

// initialize SWS context for software scaling
SwsContext *sws_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width,
pCodecCtx->height,
bgra_pix_fmt,
pCodecCtx->width,
pCodecCtx->height,
yuv420p_pix_fmt,
SWS_BILINEAR,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL
);

```
// Convert the image from its native format to RGB
sws_scale(sws_ctx, (uint8_t const * const *)pFrameRGB->data, pFrameRGB->linesize, 0, pCodecCtx->height, pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize);
//  konvertering går mot høyre

av_frame_free(&pFrameRGB);

return 1;
```

}

Not super fast but it worked